# Extract hashtags - What's faster preg_match_all() or a strpos() loop

Tags: regex, performance, preg-match-all, hashtag, strpos

I've written a basic function to extract hashtags '#hashtag' from strings. The function is based on a strpos() loop.

I think there is more potential for optimizations and it would be really nice if you could show how to make it faster.

Compared to alphanumeric preg_match_all() it is not much faster. I've tested it on a string with 350000 Tags, surrounded by some text.

Results:

```
350000 Tags extracted in 0.89877200126648 seconds // preg_match_all

350000 Tags extracted in 0.61978793144226 seconds // strpos loop
```

Used functions:

```
preg_match_all():
pattern  = '/(^|\s)\#\w+/';
preg_match_all( $pattern, $txt, $r, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );

strpos() Loop:

const _MAX_NUM_HASHTAGS_    = 10;
const _MAX_NUM_USERADDS_    = 10;
const _MIN_LENGTH_HASHTAGS_ = 3;   // including '#'
const _MAX_LENGTH_HASHTAGS_ = 30;  // including '#'
```

....

```
$txt                = $this->_postText;
$hash_tags          = array();
$stop               = false;
$hash_tag_prefix    = '#';
$hash_tag_suffix    = ' ';
$hash_tag_preffixes = array( ' ', ',', '!', '.', '?', '-', '_' );
$i                  = 0;
$end_pos            = 0;

while ( false === $stop ) {

    $i++;
    #if( $i === self::_MAX_NUM_HASHTAGS_ ){ $stop = true; }

    // if the tag is not at the beginning of our text
    // we need to validate that the tag is not part of
    // a normal string like /linksource.de?tag=tag#anchor
    // or textline#notatag
    $start_pos = strpos( $txt, $hash_tag_prefix, $end_pos );

    if( false === $start_pos ){ 

        $stop = true; 

    }

    else{

        if( $start_pos !== 0 && ! in_array( $txt[$start_pos-1], $hash_tag_preffixes ) ){

            // not a tag
            // we use this start position
            // as offset position for the next run
            $end_pos = $start_pos+1;


        }

        else{

            // should be a tag

            $end_pos = strpos( $txt, $hash_tag_suffix, $start_pos );

            if( false === $end_pos ){ $end_pos = strlen( $txt ); }

            $tag_length      = $end_pos-$start_pos;
            $tag_length_true = $tag_length-2; 

            if( $tag_length_true < self::_MIN_LENGTH_HASHTAGS_ ){

                // tag is too short
                $hash_tags[] = 'Tag was too short ';

            }

            elseif( $tag_length_true > self::_MAX_LENGTH_HASHTAGS_ ){

                // tag is too long
                $hash_tags[] = 'Tag was too long ';

            }

            else{

                $hash_tags[] = rTrim( substr( $txt, $start_pos, $tag_length ), ', ' );

            }

        }  

    }

}
```

Comment: Should probably check out [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to improve upon working code.

Comment: Is there a reason 350.000 iterations in way less than a second isn't fast enough? "Premature optimizations" and so on.

Comment: Doing it for gaining knowledge.

Comment: better yet, use explode.

Comment: Try it one way, then try the other, and then you can see which one is faster.  If you need more granular explanation of how long things are taking in PHP than simply "run it and count the seconds", then look at XDebug (http://xdebug.org)

Comment: I don't think explode would fit here. I see several cases where it makes tagvalidation more complicated. explode() on '#' would kill html anchors and other things. explode() on whitespace would do it but then it wouldn't find #tag1,#tag2. The script above takes care of some punctuations and detects #tag,#tag and !#tag and ?#tag etc..